# Filter a Dash data table via callback without having to re-send the data?

Tags: python, plotly-dash

In Dash, I'm trying to filter the data in response to another component (e.g. dropdown), without the user clicking on the table. In addition, I don't want to filter the data with pandas behind the scenes.

I'm looking for a table property that takes a filtering instruction if you will, and acts on already-loaded data.

Answer (score -2):

I fond a solution by using the Dash data table 'filter_query' property.
Just send the query in string form, and to turn off the filters send another empty string.

Example string to filter column 'Name' where entries contain 'Ana':

```
"{Name} contains 'Ana'"
```

This way you don't need to slice the data with pandas, just use the native Dash data table filtering capabilities.

Minimal Dash example with a table and a button to filter/unfilter data via 'query_string'.

```
import dash
from dash import dcc, dash_table, html, dcc
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
from dash.exceptions import PreventUpdate
import pandas as pd

#Initialize Dash
#––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––

app = dash.Dash(__name__,)

#Data
#––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––
data = {'Name': ['Ana', 'nick', 'Tom', 'jack', 'Tom'],
        'Age': [19, 21, 19, 18, 32]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

#App callbacks (enable interactivity):
#––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––
@app.callback(
    Output('data-table', 'filter_query'),
    Output('button-filter-ana','children'),
    Input('button-filter-ana', 'n_clicks'),
)
def update_output(n_clicks):

    if n_clicks is not None:
        if n_clicks%2 != 0 :
            return ["({Name} contains 'Ana')","Turn off 'Ana' filter"]
        elif n_clicks%2 == 0:
            return ["","Only show entries that contain 'Ana'"]
    else:
        raise PreventUpdate

#App Layout:
#––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––
app.layout = html.Div(
    children=[
        dcc.Loading(
            id='loading-component',
            children=[
                dash_table.DataTable(
                            id='data-table',
                            data=df.to_dict('records'),
                            columns=[{"name": i, "id": i} for i in df.columns],
                            style_table={'height': '300px', 'width': '300px'},
                            filter_action="native",
                            sort_mode="single",
                ),
                html.Button('Only show entries that contain Ana', n_clicks=0,id='button-filter-ana'),
            ]
        ),
    ]
)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #Run the app
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

[Gif: Table filtering via 'filter_query'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AY4gX.gif)

Here's Dash documentation regarding the filtering syntax:
https://dash.plotly.com/datatable/filtering